# How do I add HTML breaks before a literal list bullet • with regular expressions?

Tags: mysql, regex, perl

I have an odd situation in pulling info from a database to display a webpage.

The administrator copies and pastes info into a `mediumtext latin1_swedish_ci` field (the description column).

There are • bullets in the data, not `<li>`.

I am already doing a little formatting before displaying in Perl with:

```
my $string = $Description;
my @sentences = split(/(?:(?<=\.|\!|\?)(?<!Mr\.|Dr\.)(?<!U\.S\.A\.)\s+(?=[A-Z]))/, $string);

for (@sentences) {
#TRIED THIS $_ =~ s/•/<br />•/g;
print qq~ $_ <br /><br />~;
}
```

Which works pretty well making new lines after periods. No complaints, yet.

However, the "bulleted" lists are all run together like `List•foo•bar•nonewline`.

Obviously, I would like:

```
List

•foo

•bar

•nonewline
```

Is this possible? Does the old "garbage in, garbage out" rule kill this one?

I would just like to start a newline before the bullets.
There is no HTML in the field and I have no control over that aspect.
I can only control how it is displayed in the webpage in which HTML is obviously at my disposal.

Would [HTML::FormatText](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aFormatText) be of any assistance here?

I appreciate verbose examples as I am very new to this.
Thinking ahead, what if she pasted in different bullet types at times?

Comment: Sorry, the desired list example above came out double spaced. Desired is single.

Comment: Another note: In the database itself, the formatting is correct!

Comment: Have you tried to uncomment the line `#TRIED THIS ...` ? If so what did you obtain ?

Comment: Looks like "tried this" would give an error. It should be s:•:<br/>•:g so that "/" needn't be escaped.

Comment: @Dallaylaen   _$ =~ s/:•:/<br />•/g;   Like that???

Comment: OR LIKE perl -pi -e 's:•:<br/>•:g' $_;   ???

Comment: The second one. s/Foo/Bar/, s:Foo:Bar: and s{Foo} {Bar} are all the same thing, provided you don't use the delimiting symbol within Foo or Bar. Or you could quote it: s/\//\\\//g -- but it's a way to an untrappable mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s/•/<br />•/g
```

Did you take a close look at the error message you got when you tried that? If you're using a slash as the delimiter in s///, then any slashes in the pattern or replacement will need to be escaped.

```
s/•/<br \/>•/g
```

But to make it more readable, use different delimiters.

```
s|•|<br />•|g
```